# How to get text from EditText from within a dynamically created view

Tags: android

So I have a vertical LinearLayout with an Add button, every time it’s clicked it adds a view with the custom layout I made that has 2 textViews and 2 editText. The TextViews ask the user for X and Y locations, and what I want to do is get the input from the EditTexts and display it all line by line in another TextView, but my problem is I can’t figure out how to get the text from these EditText. Could anyone help me with how to get the text from these EditText or does anyone have recommendations on a better way to accomplish this?

```
LinearLayout parentLinearLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_holes);
    parentLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.parentLinearLayout);
}

public void onAddField(View v){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);

    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, + 1);


}
```

This is the code i have so far. So far i start off with an add and done button, and when you click add it adds this layout I made.

field.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewX"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="X"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextX"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewY"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Y"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextY"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="REMOVE" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to keep a list of all the "fields" you have made

```
private List<View> rowViews = new List<View>();

public void onAddField(View v){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
    rowViews.add(rowView);
    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, + 1);

}
```

This way you have a list of all of your views with unique indices for each. Then getting the text is as simple as `EditText ed = rowViews.get(index).findViewById(R.id.editTextX);
ed.getText();`

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this example:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText(editText.getText());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

especially the line:

```
textView.setText(editText.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommendations : 
Use **RecyclcerView** instead of LinearLayout for add dyanamic view its can be hadle easily.

For RecyclcerView, you need to make an adapter class to define an addItem method to add view and you can easity get text from EditText.

Look like this :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.salesappdemo.R;
import com.salesappdemo.interfaces.RecyclerClickListener;
import com.salesappdemo.model.TaskModel;
import com.salesappdemo.utils.LogUtil;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

/**
 * Created by Jaydip on 6/28/2018.
 */

public class FormAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FormAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "FormAdapter";

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<TaskModel> arrayList;
    private RecyclerClickListener clickListener;

    public FormAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<TaskModel> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_form, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v, new CustomEditTextListener());
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        //Set Data
        TaskModel model = arrayList.get(position);

        viewHolder.customEditTextListener.updatePosition(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        viewHolder.edtTaskName.setText(model.getTaskName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //For Item Click Event
    public void setClickListener(RecyclerClickListener itemClickListener) {
        clickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public ArrayList<TaskModel> getList() {
        return arrayList;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.edtTaskName)
        EditText edtTaskName;
        @BindView(R.id.btnAdd)
        ImageView btnAdd;
        @BindView(R.id.btnDelete)
        ImageView btnDelete;
        @BindView(R.id.rlMain)
        RelativeLayout rlMain;

        public CustomEditTextListener customEditTextListener;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, CustomEditTextListener customEditTextListener) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

            this.customEditTextListener = customEditTextListener;
            this.edtTaskName.addTextChangedListener(customEditTextListener);
        }

        @OnClick({R.id.btnAdd, R.id.btnDelete})
        public void onViewClicked(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnAdd:
                    clickListener.onClickEvent(view, getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
                case R.id.btnDelete:
                    clickListener.onClickEvent(view, getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private class CustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher {
        private int position;

        public void updatePosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            if (arrayList != null) {
                arrayList.get(position).setTaskName(charSequence.toString());
                LogUtil.e(TAG, " :: onTextChanged :: position : " + position + "  Text : " + arrayList.get(position).getTaskName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    }

    public void addItem(int position, TaskModel model) {
        if (arrayList != null) {
            arrayList.add(model);
            notifyItemInserted(position);
            LogUtil.e(TAG, " :: addItem :: Success :: position : " + position);
        }
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        if (arrayList != null) {
            arrayList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, arrayList.size());
            LogUtil.e(TAG, " :: remove :: Success :: position : " + position);
        }
    }
}
```

And Add & Remove View from Activity like this :

```
 @OnClick({R.id.btnAddTask})
    public void onViewClicked(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnAddTask:

                LogUtil.e(TAG, " :: Clicked :: btnAddTask :: ");
                if (formAdapter != null) {
                    if (formAdapter.getList().size() == 0 ||
                            !TextUtils.isEmpty(formAdapter.getList().get(formAdapter.getList().size() - 1).getTaskName()))
                        formAdapter.addItem(formAdapter.getList().size(), new TaskModel());
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter a Task Name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                break;
        }
    }
```

**Remove :**

```
@Override
public void onClickEvent(View view, int position) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnDelete:

            if (formAdapter != null) {
                formAdapter.remove(position);
            }

            break;
    }

}
```